# How we can decrypt data in rails raw sql query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, attr-encrypted

In rails i have used gem => attr_encrypted
using above gem data encrypted in PostgreSQL DB table.

using model name can be decrypt.
But how I can do in raw query in select query
like
i have column encrypted in table like
email encrypted and email_encrypted_iv

now I want to use raw query in rails application
like

```
User.select('email, id')
```

Using above query how we can get data decrypted in select query?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? If you're on Rails 7 it has built in attribute encryption so you do not need that gem. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html

Comment: Rails => 4.2.4 and ruby 2.3.1 , In model i have given secret_key and defined column name as attr_encrypted, so in db table column be like encrypted_email

Comment: Why bother with encryption when you're on a version of Rails that was EOL eons ago and has known secuity vulnerabities? You should be focused on updating instead.

Comment: Yes, it will updated in soon time,  in column previous data stored in plain text, but cause of security added encryption for db table data store, but in some model field data fetched in raw query.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without hydrating full `User` objects and letting `attr_encrypted` do its thing. This is the entire purpose of this functionality: to make data at rest (fields in the database) unreadable to the database or whoever steals your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sergio is right, you can't decrypt the database data via SQL when Rails did the encrypting.

You'll have to pull out the record(s) with Rails and do the decryption via the gem.